# Euler diagram margin and font size using eulerr package

Tags: r, venn-diagram

**Question**

I made a Euler diagram using the `eulerr` package. However, sometimes the boundary is out of the canvas margin. Therefore, I want to adjust the margin. Besides, I tried to adjust the font size but failed.

**Code and Results**

A small example of the problem.

```
pacman::p_load(dplyr, eulerr)
my_dt <- tibble(
  value = c(1:8), 
  group_a = c(TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
  group_b = c(TRUE,  FALSE,  TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE),
  group_c = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE)
)

# the diagram changes with the seed
set.seed(1234)
plot(euler(my_dt[, c("group_a", "group_b", "group_c")]), quantities = TRUE)
```

To adjust the margin, I tried `par(mar = c(2, 2, 2, 2)` before runing the `plot(euler(my_dt[, c("group_a", "group_b", "group_c")]), quantities = TRUE)`, but it didn't work. Besides, to adjust the font size of the label, I tried `plot(euler(my_dt[, c("group_a", "group_b", "group_c")]), quantities = TRUE, cex.lab = 1)` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach to adjusting the label and quantity sizes and providing a "margin".

Check out the documentation under `plot.euler` for other formatting options.

As `eulerr` is based on `grid` you can provide margins in effect by adjusting the size of the viewport used for plotting. The answer shows a plot reduced to 80% of the original height and width.

Although I noticed that the relative positions of the venn diagram elements changes as you rerun the code I never found that the circles   straying outside the canvas margin.

`set.seed()` did not seem to change anything.

```r
library(eulerr)
library(grid)

my_dt <- data.frame(
  value = c(1:8), 
  A = c(TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
  B = c(TRUE,  FALSE,  TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE),
  C = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE)
)

p <- plot(euler(my_dt[, c("A", "B", "C")]), 
     quantities = list(cex = 2),
     labels = list(cex = 2))

# edit the viewport dimensions

p$vp$width <- unit(0.8, "npc")
p$vp$height <- unit(0.8, "npc")


p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>